Связано ли написание всех слов с заглавной буквы на русском языке в Интернете с влиянием английского языка?
Много лет назад пользователи русскоязычного сегмента Интернета начали писать в предложениях все слова на русском языке с заглавной буквы, особенно в ВК, заголовках к постам, а также в названиях видео в сети Интернет. Почему в английском языке написание всех слов в заголовках с заглавной буквы кроме союзов и частиц является нормой, а в русском языке нет?
Например, "Москва Не Сразу Строилась"

Для начала хорошо бы узнать, почему в английском названия в ИТ-интерфейсе с заглавных букв, типа "Создать Документ". На русском это выглядит очень дико, с этим трудно смириться. Откуда в английском это пошло? Может из газет? Или это чисто компьютерная фишка?

Иллюстрации к текстам вопросов на сайте не приняты, но здесь хотелось бы видеть не слова, а скрины, подтверждающие наблюдения про «много лет назад» и «все слова в предложениях на русском языке с заглавной буквы».
